# ngMessage does not display multiple messages

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-messages, angular-forms

I want display two errors **required** and **invalid email**. I have added a regex pattern to my input code to check for invalid emails.

```
<input ng-model="newUser.email" type="mail" name="email" placeholder="Email (required)" ng-required="true" ng-pattern = '/^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i'>
```

but my ngMessage is not showing any message for invalid email , it only shows message for email required.

```
        <div ng-messages="signUp.email.$error" ng-messages-multiple>
            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
            <div ng-message="email">Please enter a valid email address.</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: AngularJS 1.5.5

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div ng-message="pattern">Please enter a valid email address.</div>
```

This solved the issue.